# Heroku: Unable to create ticket

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

When I click on Create Ticket, I am asked to categorize the problem and then it takes me to a different screen from where I cannot create a ticket.

Answer (score 2):

Once you navigate to the right section for your problem, there's another 'Create a Ticket' button at the bottom of the page that works. The top nav 'Create a Ticket' doesn't currently.