# How do I recover my Heroku account when I can't even sign in to create a ticket?

Tags: heroku

My Heroku account was flagged automatically and locked due to suspicious activity, which is good security. I raised a ticket with Heroku at the time to unlock the account, they required some information from me, including identity verification, which I provided. Since this they have not responded to my ticket and it appears a bot has automatically closed the issue, with no resolution.

Now it asks me to log a new ticket but I can't actually log in with my account to create a ticket. So I made a new account, logged a ticket with reference to the initial ticket and have had no response. About a week later, it appears my second account must be locked as I am unable to log in with this account. Probably valid since I had to create a temporary email account to sign up so I could raise a ticket.

The Heroku help docs are [pretty useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873262/heroku-unable-to-create-ticket). It's essentially an endless loop of Create Ticket > Help Center > Search > Read Article > Create Ticket...repeat. Even if I get to a sign in page I can't get by it anymore due to yet another account disabled.

That account is linked to my official email address and is why I'd like either the account unlocked or the email address released. It seems as though creating a new account isn't a viable solution either, given that I have tried and that account is now locked too.

I have tried the actions described at [What should I do if I can't log into my Heroku account?](https://help.heroku.com/UTTFTDN8/what-should-i-do-if-i-can-t-log-into-my-heroku-account)

There doesn't appear to be any way of getting in touch with a human short of calling an office or a sales rep for enterprise which I feel is the wrong approach. Perhaps this is where my journey ends with Heroku although that seems unfair.

So instead of creating a spamming cycle of new accounts and tickets all referencing each other, how do I go about restoring access to my main account and initial ticket?